# How to easily switch between proxy methods from terminal

Tags: command-line

How do I switch between the proxy methods(none,manual,automatic) and apply it system wide from terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some examples, using `gsettings`:

```bsh
# setting a proxy manual
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host '192.168.10.100'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none' # this will disable proxy setting

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'auto' # this will set the proxy automatic
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `dconf`:

```
dconf write /system/proxy/mode 'none' # this will disable proxy setting
dconf write /system/proxy/mode 'auto' # this will set the proxy automatic
dconf write /system/proxy/mode 'manual' #this will allow you to use the manual settings
dconf write /system/proxy/http/host 'somehost'
dconf write /system/proxy/http/port '1234'
```

Comment: VALUE arguments must be in GVariant format, so e.g. a string must include explicit quotes: "'foo'" [https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html]